# Macbook keeps disconnecting from hotspot Wifi, which works well

Tags: network, wifi, internet-sharing

I've been having this problem for months, and I finally need help.

I found other topics on connection problems, but not quite the one I have.

When I'm at home I use a Wifi hotspot from my Android phone which has unlimited data, and my Macbook tends to disconnect quite often from this network, sometimes more often than others.

However my phone still has internet and other devices, like my playstation, can connect without problems.

Even more surprising, if do something that "continuously" uses internet, like Zoom calls, the Macbook almost never loses the connection.

Furthermore, when my Macbook disconnects, turning on the Playstation, also connected to the hotspot Wifi, seems to resolve the connection issue!

The Macbook has no problems to connect to any other Wifi network, like at work or at friend's places.

Do you have any clues on how to stabilise the connection of my Macbook when using the hotspot from my phone?

Comment: It may be that the hotspot disconnects automatically after sometime when it detects no network activity over the hotspot wifi. This could be to save battery. So check if you have some power saving mode or battery saver app that does this. When Wifi hotspot disconnects, macOS will try to connect to it or keep searching for others known wifi's to connect to.

Comment: Also check the tethering and mobile hotspot settings - Android 7 and above have a "timeout" setting which you  set it to "never turn off".

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I checked and there are no power saving options activated. 
I cannot find any "timeout setting" in my phone, I can only choose a password, and Activate USB, Wifi or bluetooth sharing.

Comment: Please tell us the Android version you use?

Comment: It's Android 7.1.2 on a Fairphone 2
Thanks again for the help

Comment: Ok. Follow the instructions in this guide - [Fix Your Portable WiFi Hotspot Turn Off Automatically](https://gadgetstouse.com/blog/2015/10/29/wifi-hotspot-idle-issues/) and let us know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I've found for the issue is to have something running in the background that continuously uses the network. For example, keep Spotify playing music.